# ExecuteScalar SQLException: scalar variable not declared

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to check if a user exists within a table in SQL-Server. I have created connection strings, opened a connection -

```
            var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogEngine"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(settings);
            using (conn)
            {
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var checkUser = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.be_Users WHERE UserName = @UserName";
                    using (SqlCommand userquery = new SqlCommand(checkUser,conn))
                    {
                        var parma = userquery.Parameters;
                        parma.AddWithValue("@UserName", activedirectory.DisplayName);
                        int UserExist = (int)userquery.ExecuteScalar();

                        if (UserExist > 0)
                        {
                            //Username exist
                            AuthenticateUser(staffId, password, rmb);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Username doesn't exist.
                            var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.be_Users (BlogID, UserName, Password, LastLoginTime, EmailAddress, Department)" + "VALUES (@BlogID, @UserName, @Password, @LastLoginTime, @EmailAddress, @Department)";
                            using (SqlCommand qe = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery))
                            {

                                var parms = qe.Parameters;
                                parms.AddWithValue("@BlogID", Blog.CurrentInstance.Id.ToString());
                                parms.AddWithValue("@UserName", activedirectory.DisplayName); 
                                parms.AddWithValue("@Password", (passwordFormat == MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed ? Utils.HashPassword(DEFAULT_PASSWORD) : DEFAULT_PASSWORD));
                                parms.AddWithValue("@LastLoginTime", DateTime.Now);
                                parms.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", DEFAULT_EMAIL);
                                parms.AddWithValue("@Department", activedirectory.department);

                                qe.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            AuthenticateUser(staffId, password, rmb);
                        }
                    }conn.Close();
                }
```

I keep getting this error - An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName".

The exception occurs at the `int UserExist = (int)userquery.ExecuteScalar();` line.

Please, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have *added* a parameter here:

```
parma.AddWithValue("@UserName", activedirectory.DisplayName);
```

My guess would be that `activedirectory.DisplayName` **is `null`**. A curious glitch in ADO.NET is that parameters with `null` values **are not passed**. To pass a `null` down to the database, you need to pass `DBNull.Value`. So:

```
parma.AddWithValue("@UserName", ((object)activedirectory.DisplayName) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

or more longhand:

```
object displayName = activedirectory.DisplayName;
if(displayName == null) { displayName = DBNull.Value; }
parma.AddWithValue("@UserName", displayName);
```

However! This then invites the question: what *should* this code do if the display name is `null`? The SQL query shown clearly won't behave in the expected way.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you please change your code to below

```
var parma = new SqlParameter("@UserName",activedirectory.DisplayName);
                userquery.Parameters.Add(parma);
```

Comment: um... why? is there a reason? in particular, is there a reason that is related to the question? I would **not** expect that change to make any difference to the issue reported in the question.